# How to convert java.time.format.TemoralAccessor to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, java.util.date, datetime-conversion, temporal

How can I convert TemporalAccessor to java.util.Date?

```
TemporalAccessor accessor = functionReturnsTemporalAccessor()
Date date = Date.from(accessor)
```

Date.from() does not accept TemporalAccessor, is there any way to convert to java.util.Date?

Comment: I think you should rather step back and ask why that function returns that type. The official javadoc says **This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be widely used in application code.** It is inconvenient because your code shouldnt be dealing with it ...

Comment: DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse(...) returns TemporalAccessor

Answer (score 6):

> `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse(...)` returns
> `TemporalAccessor`

True. Don’t use that method. Use the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse(CharSequence)` instead. Example:

```
    String isoOffsetDateTimeString = "2020-11-13T21:07:38.146120+01:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(isoOffsetDateTimeString);
    Instant asInstant = dateTime.toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(asInstant);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Output in my time zone:

> Fri Nov 13 21:07:38 CET 2020

Also don’t use `Date` if you can avoid it. That class is poorly designed and long outdated.  I am assuming that you need one for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now.

The one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse()` accepts exactly the format specified by `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, so is a good replacement for what you were trying.

While it *would* have been possible to convert the `TemporalAccessor` returned from `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse()` to a `Date`, only impractical, you generally cannot convert a `TemporalAccessor` to a `Date`. Each `TemporalAccessor` has some fields that it supports and some that it doesn’t. Since a `Date` (despite the name) is a point in time, the `TemporalAccessor` would need to define a point in time, and not all `TemporalAccessor` objects do that.

If you have been used to the old, poorly designed and now long outdated Java date and time classes like `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, then you have been used calling the methods `parse` and `format` on the formatter. With java.time the conventional way is opposite: We now usually call the static `parse` method on the date-time class, for example `OffsetDateTime`, optionally giving a `DateTimeFormatter` as argument (which wasn’t necessary in this case). Similarly we call the `format` method on the date-time object, again passing a `DateTimeFormatter` as argument.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it depends on the type of `TemporalAccessor` your method returns. But the `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` output you mentioned in comments should be possible to handle with this:

```java
TemporalAccessor accessor = functionReturnsTemporalAccessor();
Date date = new Date(Instant.from(accessor).toEpochMilli());
```